# C# performance counter Timer100Ns. How to?

Tags: c#, performance

I have an application which monitors a particular event and then starts to calculate things once it happens. Events are irregular and can come in any pattern from bunches in a sec to none for long time..

**I want to measure %% of time the application is busy (similar to CPU % Usage)**

I want to use `Timer100Ns` counter

Two questions:

1. Do I increment it by hardware ticks or by DateTime ticks (e.g. if I use Stopwatch - do I use sw.ElapsedTicks or sw.Elapsed.Ticks) ?
2. Do I need a base counter for it?

so I am about to write something like this:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Do some operation which is irregular by nature
sw.Stop();

// Measure utilization of the application
myCounterOfTypeTimer100Ns.IncrementBy(sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
```

Will it do ?

**EDIT :** I experimented with it a bit and now its even more confusing.. It actually shows the values I increment it by. Not %%.

Comment: nothing interesting in that class. its just a holder of a field which is PerformanceCounter of type Timer100Ns. The MSDN says : `A percentage counter that shows the active time of a component as a percentage of the total elapsed time of the sample interval. `.. May be there are other ways. But I'd like to find out how to use this one.

Comment: Wait a sec - what it has to do with a multi-counter? a multi-counter needed when you track several metrics at once.. totally random information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery unravelled. It currently appears that I don't use it in the way it was supposed to be used (or rather I didn't read TFM properly). If the sampling interval is 1s (as in perf mon live window) and you intervals are more than 1s then it shows you a nonsense number... To achieve smoothness, the activity you are trying to measure must be really fractions of 1s.. Otherwise this counter is not a good idea..

The answer for this kind of problem (although its not obvious, but still disturbing that nobody suggested it in a week) is actually `SampleCounter`.